# Masstransit bus is always null even if initialized

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, castle-windsor, masstransit

I am using MT 3.1.0 and Castle windsor 3.3.0.

Using windsor installer I have initialized container.

```
 public void Install(IWindsorContainer container,IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "testq", e =>
            {
                e.EnableMessageScope();
                e.LoadFrom(container);
            });
        });
        container.Register(Component.For<IBus>().Instance(busControl));

        busControl.Start();
    }
```

Inside Application_Start() configured container

```
 _container = WindsorConfiguration.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

From API Controller

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/Test")]
 public class TestController : ApiController
 {
    private readonly IBus _bus;
 }

 public TestController(IBus bus)
 {
    _bus = bus;
 }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("PublishMessage")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PublishMessage()
    {
        await _bus.Publish(new TestMessage
        {
            TestId = 1
        });

        return Ok("Success!");
    }
```

It throws null reference exception at _bus.Publish

Comment: Why 3.1.0, and not 3.5.7? Also, if you're getting null, make sure the bus instance isn't being disposed by the API controller. The lifecycle should be singleton, and long-lived until the application is shutdown.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Just figured the problem, I was not adding controllers in container and so constructor was not getting called. your comment just bring the light on api controller and figured it.  
 container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestyleScoped());